# Mount google cloud storage folders to google ai platform job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to setup a basic pytorch pipeline with google ai platform.

I don't understand how google storage works with ai-platform jobs.

I am trying to mount several google storage blobs to my ai-platform jobs but completely can not find how I can do it. I need to do two things: 1) access dataset from my python pytorch code and 2) after train finish access logs and models

In the Google AI Platform tutorials the only relevant concept I found is manually downloading the dataset to job local storage via python google.cloud.storage API and uploading the result after the program finish. But surely this is unacceptable in the situation of quick research iterations (because of large datasets and possible crashes in the middle of training).

What is the solutions for such a basic problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Storage Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount your bucket and use it like it was a local folder to avoid data download.

Comment: Yes and no. Yes for prototyping, no for training. The reasons are performances and cost ( class A request billed). And low performance imply longer training and thus higher cost.